# calculate strwidth without calling plot.new

Tags: r

How can one use `strwidth` without opening a plotting window as it seems to do by default?

So `strwidth('this is cool', font = 12, units = 'in')` call `plot.new`.  Can this behavior be stopped?
If so how?

Answer (score 1):

Ugly workaround, but might be useful in some cases (for example I use this to compare the width of different strings, so a relative width is just fine): store the results of `strwidth` for each ASCII or other common characters in a `data.frame`, then use a look-up function instead of directly calling `strwidth`. I've added this small utility to the [`rapportools` package](https://github.com/Rapporter/rapportools/blob/master/R/strwidth.R):

```
> strwidthest('R')
[1] 3.18499
>  strwidthest('R is awesome!')
[1] 28.66491
```

The results are returned in millimeter for a 12pt sans font.

Answer (score 0):

The default measurement is in "user" coordinates (which the help page clearly states requires plot.new() to be called), but if you choose a different coordinate system, say 'inches', it will not need to have an open device to create a result.

```
str.ex <- c("W","w","I",".","WwI.")
sw <- strwidth(str.ex, units="inches"); sw
[1] 0.08333333 0.08333333 0.08333333 0.08333333 0.33333333
```

I am not getting plot.new being called, although I see that you tried supplying units as an argument.

Comment: It does though, at least on my Linux box with R 3.0.0... in that it opens a new plot device.

Comment: DWin I tried your code exactly and get the same thing as in mine above.